# FileStream.Read - Read a stream without using a loop

Tags: c#, filestream

How would I read a filestream without using a loop? When I use this code it only reads 5714 bytes instead of 1048576 bytes

```
byte[] Buffer = new byte[1048576];
ByteSize = downloadstream.Read(Buffer, 0,Buffer.Lenght);
```

If I use this loop it works fine

```
while ((ByteSize = downloadstream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    //write stream to file
}
```

So how would I read an entire stream without using a loop?
Thanks, would appreciate any help.
I have to read all of the data into a buffer and then write it. Sorry I didn't mention this earlier.

**EDIT:** You can use this code as well to read a stream into a buffer at once:

```
using (var streamreader = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(streamreader);
                buffer = streamreader.ToArray();
            }
```

Comment: In your top code snippet, you declare a buffer named `DownloadBuffer`, but then you read into a different buffer, one called `Buffer`.  Is this a typo, or is that actually how your program looks?  Also, `Buffer.Lenght` is a typo.  I'd edit your question, but I want to know what you intended first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read the *entire* file in *one go*, I suggest using `File.ReadAllBytes` for binary files:

```
 byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\MyFile.dat");
```

And `File.ReadAllText` / `File.ReadAllLines` for text ones:

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\MyFile.txt");

 string[] lines = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\MyOtherFile.txt");
```

**Edit**: in case of web

```
  byte[] data;

  using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true; // if you have a proxy etc.

    data = wc.DownloadData(myUrl); 
  }
```

when `myUrl` is `@"https://www.google.com"` I've got `data.Length == 45846`

Comment: @Dinindu Perera: Are you looking for `byte[] data = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);` then?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your file contains text then you could use a stream reader and just pass in your FileStream to the constructor (below I create a new FileStream to open a file):

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open)))
        {
            string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: `StreamReader` is for text.  There's no indication that the OP's file is a text file.

Comment: Thanks - adding a comment to that effect.  Assuming the encoding is known the string could easily be converted into a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) on `Stream.Read`:

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached.

So it appears that it's totally legal for `Stream.Read` to read less than the buffer length, provided it tells you that's what it did.

Comment: Yes I agree. I'm just wondering how to do it in one go. @adv12